# Insert PHP variable into a HTML table

Tags: php

I'm new to Web development programming , and i'm trying to insert a PHP variable into a HTML table with divs, but it's showing me blank

```
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th>sdads</th>
                                        <th>Browser</th>
                                        <th>Platform(s)</th>
                                        <th>Engine version</th>
                                        <th>CSS grade</th>
                                     </tr>

                                </thead>
```

That's not the full code.

If i wanted to put a PHP variable where `<th>sdads</th>` is, how i could do that?
I tried this: `<th><?php echo $test; ?></th>`, but it didn't work (the variable is declared on the start of the code by `$test="test";`

Comment: Did you assign anything to $test? Does your filename ends with .php? ex: `index.php`

Comment: Please, inspect the page and check if there is something that you aren't seeing. Is the file named `something.php?` (Check if the extension is `.php`)

Comment: What do you mean by 'it didn't work' ? Any error or this doesn't work as expected ? What do you have and what are you expecting ?

Comment: yes, i did, on the beginning of the <body> tag;

Comment: Can you show us all of your file content? Probably you don't set anything into $test variable before you use it.

Comment: What was the output when you added the PHP snippet?

Comment: I can't post full code(exceed limit), but now i tried to declare variable before the encho and the th still empty, the text just disappeared on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th><?php echo $test; ?></th>
                                    <th>Browser</th>
                                    <th>Platform(s)</th>
                                    <th>Engine version</th>
                                    <th>CSS grade</th>
                                 </tr>

                            </thead>
```

There is only one reason that it will not work. you have problem with PHP installations or you have error reporting turned off.

Change PHP.ini or if you are a begginer just Download latest xmap and install it

Comment: You can't refer people as 'noob', be polite. Prefer the word 'beginner'.

Comment: Sorry sir I though both were same sorry my error

Comment: I just searched the Internet noob is originated from word "newbie"  which means begginer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to code below way? it works fine in my envionment. And must be you have to save the file using .php extension. Thanks.

```
    <?php $test = 'sdads'; ?>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $test; ?></th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
         </tr>

    </thead>
```